# XSLT "match" and "if" meaning

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm really new to XSLT and I'm struggling to understand some codes. Following is the code I don't understand:

```
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

and:

```
    <xsl:if test="*">
```

What does it mean when you test a * symbol?

Comment: It is a wildcard - match anything.

Comment: The first code is Identity transform template, which is used to copy every node and attribute present in the input as-is; there are numerous questions on the same on stackoverflow, you can go through some to understand how it works. The second is a test on the current node to check if it has any child elements(only elments and not "anything"); if yes, the `xsl:if` is entered, else not.

Comment: How are you approaching the task of teaching yourself the language? Asking on SO whenever you find a construct you haven't seen before isn't the most efficient approach. I might be old-fashioned, but when I tackle a new language the first thing I do is to get hold of a book with a good index, and spend a couple of evenings reading it before I try to write any code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first template is the basis for an [identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform), and often used as the basis for a "push style" stylesheet in which the default behavior is to simply copy the input into the output. More specific templates are added in order to customize the behavior and produce different content.

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This template will match any attribute `@*` and any node (element, comment, text, or processing instruction) `node()`, and is shorthand for: `*|comment()|text()|processing-instruction()`

When any of those items are matched, the template first copies the matched item, and then invokes `xsl:apply-templates` for any attributes or `node()` children of the context item. In the case of an attribute, `text()`, `comment()`, or `processing-instruction()` there will be no attributes or child `node()`. For an element, it could match either of those things. Unless there is a more specific template, it will simply get matched with this template and copy the matched item and continuing processing its attributes and children (if any).

In the case of the `xsl:if`:

```
<xsl:if test="*">
```

That tests to see if there are any child elements (relative from the context node). If there are any, then the condition is satisfied and the test evaluates to `true()` and whatever is placed inside the if will be applied.

For more information about the abbreviated syntax, see the spec:
https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev